# PHP framework to reduce image resolution for iPhone and iPad

Tags: php, ios, image, web-services, frameworks

I'm developing an iphone app where it shows the feed of posts with images(500X500 retina size). And I'm getting those post from web service, the web users also can post to the web service. So, my problem is the when the web user uploads an images with image resolution(say 3000X4000 something like that), and when I load the feed in the app, it causes memory issues because of the image sizes.

So, I need to know which is the better way to reduce the resolution of image, on iOS side or web side(php backend)? If PHP side is the best place to reduce the image resolution, please provide me with some best PHP framework(specifically for iOS devices) to covert the image resolution.

Comment: Always enforce these things server side. php image resizeing is well documented

Comment: As @user574632 says do it on the server as the image is uploaded. Do a google on `php image resize` and you will see lots of examples, many of them here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should always resize images on the server side if it's not necessary to display the whole image in the client. It speeds up network requests, uses less bandwidth etc. and just generally gives a better user experience.

For php image resizing, check out for example this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8819561/811830